# Ripple produces .bar and .zip only, no .cod files

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I've been using Ripple to preview a Phonegap application. The preview works fine and I would like to package the app so I can test on a real device.

Using ripple, I've set the platform to WebWorks 2.0.0.

I have run package and sign, which completes successfully and gives me the following output :

```
smrtlap1307:SmartConf JElsey$ tree -L 3 bin/
bin/
├── SmartConf-BB.zip
├── device
│   └── SmartConf-BB.bar
└── simulator
    └── SmartConf-BB.bar
```

Any reason why I wouldn't be getting the .cod files? If I understand correctly, .bar files are only produced for PlayBook apps, and I need a .cod file to deploy onto a BB Curve.

Can anyone advise?

**EDIT** : This is my Ripple version

- Ripple UI (v0.9.8)
- Ripple Build & Deploy (v0.9.5)

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, bar-files are also a binary files format for BlackBerry 10 Smartphone. And I think you have packaged project for BB 10 smartphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bars are for BlackBerry PlayBook and BlackBerry 10 devices.  Ripple supports those, in addition to java-based BlackBerry devices (like for your curve).  Check the target device.